# module cordova/plugin/ios/nativecomm not found - PhoneGap 2.1 / Sencha 2.0

Tags: iphone, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have an existing iPhone project implemented with PhoneGap 2.1 and Sencha Touch 2.0. The app has run perfectly historically but I've run into some issues when picking it up again.

First, I had problem with the CordovaLib.xcodeproj, which was just colored red in the project explorer. I solved that by adding the CordovaLib folder from the Phonegap-2.1 folder to the project, according to [this blog post](http://outof.me/embedding-cordovalib-in-your-iosphonegap-app-project/#comment-216).

Now I can build and run the app, but it freezes on the splash screen. There is the "Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES" log output but nothing more. Not even from the launch function:

```
launch: function() {
   console.log("Main controller launch:");
   […]
}
```

I put a window.onerror in the js file and got this pop-up:

```
ERROR: module cordova/plugin/ios/nativecomm not found
URL: undefined
Linenumber:0
```

Supposedly, I should just run cordova_upgrade_subproject, but that didn't help.

Why is ../nativecomm not found? How do I make it found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it works now. The only thing I did was putting a console.log() in the window.onerror() function, instead of just an alert(). It seems unlikely that this would affect the application in any way, but anyhow… it works!